# Why doesn't Django recognize my installed package?

Tags: django, python-2.7, dreamhost

I am trying to install the python-oath2 library in my Python virtual environment running python 2.7.3 via Pythonbrew on a Dreamhost shared hosting file.

First I downloaded the tarball on this link and then extracted the file contents.
https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

I then `cd`ed into the extracted folder and then ran

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

This produced a new file `oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg` in the directory

```
/home/davidfaux/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

When I `import oauth2` in the Python interpreter, no errors surface. However, when I call `import oauth2` in views.py of my Django application, an error is raised:

```
Could not import myapp.views. Error was: No module named oauth2
```

I tried restarting Passenger (`touch tmp/restart.txt`), restarting Python (`pkill python`), and re-sshing into the server. I also tried `pb switch 2.7.3` to ensure that I was using the right version of Python. Why doesn't Django let me import `oauth2` if importing it works in the Python interpreter?

Comment: is it at INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Comment: Thanks - No, I did not list `oauth` in INSTALLED_APPS, but `oauth` is a Python package, not a Django app, right? Hence, why should I list it under there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process running your django application is either:

1. Not using your custom Python, so it cannot find your package
2. Has a different directory listed in `PYTHONPATH` for packages, and it cannot find it.
3. Finally, if both those aren't true - try removing all `*.pyc` files using something like this - `find . -name *.pyc -exec rm {} \;` and restart your backend server (passenger).

Comment: Thank you! How do I verify the first 2 efficiently?

Comment: Hi! I think you're right! The stack trace from Django notes files from python2.5, while I want to use python 2.7.3. How do I make Django use my python brew installation of Python 2.7.3?